# websockets/ws TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm getting an error from [websockets/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws):

```
/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:422
    event.target = target;
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'target' of reserved fields (2, 3) must be empty
    at WebSocket.onError (/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:422:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Receiver.onerror (/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:832:10)
    at Receiver.error (/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:317:8)
    at Receiver.processPacket (/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:186:12)
    at Receiver.add (/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:91:24)
    at firstHandler (/root/diag/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:767:22)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

This is not referring to any specific line in my code, so I don't even know where in my code is causing this.

Is this a bug with the new update of module or am I doing something wrong?

I haven't updated the websocket client (which is where the error is coming from) in a while.

**EDIT**

The websocket is used at two different locations:

```
// main file that then passes socket to libdiag.js
socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('authenticate', {
        method: 'token',
        credentials: token
    });
});

socket.on('authenticate', function(packet) {
    var data = JSON.parse(packet.data);
    if (packet.channel == CHANNEL && data.status == "authenticated") {
        libdiag.start(socket, CHANNEL);
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    start();
});

socket.on('error', function (err) {
    libdiag.error(err); // This is just a logger that writes to file
});
```

And this file

```
// This is libdiag.js
socket.on('data', function (packet) {
    var data = JSON.parse(packet.data);

    // New listener is requesting handshake
    if (packet.type == SOCKET_HANDSHAKE) {
        _handshake(data);
    }

    // A listener has left
    if (packet.type == SOCKET_CLOSED) {
        _listenerLeft(data);
    }

    if (packet.type == SOCKET_UPDATE) {
        _read(data);
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    libdiag.destroy(); // This calls socket.disconnect() and sets the variables to null
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to bind a [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-target) to one of your websockets callbacks, DOM Level 2 Events have their  `target` property set as `readOnly`:

```
// Introduced in DOM Level 2:
interface Event {

  // PhaseType
  const unsigned short      CAPTURING_PHASE                = 1;
  const unsigned short      AT_TARGET                      = 2;
  const unsigned short      BUBBLING_PHASE                 = 3;

  readonly attribute DOMString        type;
  readonly attribute EventTarget      target;
  readonly attribute EventTarget      currentTarget;
  readonly attribute unsigned short   eventPhase;
  readonly attribute boolean          bubbles;
  readonly attribute boolean          cancelable;
  readonly attribute DOMTimeStamp     timeStamp;
  void               stopPropagation();
  void               preventDefault();
  void               initEvent(in DOMString eventTypeArg, 
                               in boolean canBubbleArg, 
                               in boolean cancelableArg);
};
```

And it seems that in your flow, something is triggering the `onError` handler of the [websocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js), which tries to change the `event.target`:

```
function onError (event) {
    event.type = 'error';
    event.target = target;
    listener.call(target, event);
}
```

I believe this is the root cause of the error you are seeing there in your console. It would be helpful if you show us the code regarding on the events/callbacks/handlers you are binding or using with your websocket in order to determine a way to not use a DOM Level 2 event.

Comment: I updated my answer. My error handling is simply writing the content to a file. I don't do anything fancy!

Comment: Would you consider temporarily modifying the WebSocket library, the onError method, adding a console.log(event);  at the beginning of it, and paste it in your question?  It might give some sort of insight on where the error is coming from.

Comment: that's what you get on your console?

Comment: Yes. So I tracked the error, and it is coming from `Receiver.js` the function `Receiver.prototype.processPacket`

Comment: Is Reciever a dependency of yours? Of yes, can you show the code?

Comment: No, Receiver is one of the library files of `ws` module itself

Comment: Actually the stack trace starts at process._tickCallback, can you show that piece of code?